# jquery and PHP - Sending information back from php to the JS

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Thanks for all the great answers, this helps a lot!

---

Hello, I need some advice/help (obviously)

I'm pretty new to jquery/ajax in general but I have been able to do quite a bit so far.  Here is what I am TRYING to do and then what I have managed to do so far.

I am trying to emulate the wordpress post categories. Where you are writing a post and then when you want to add it to a category it lets you just create new checkbox categories on the spot!

I have managed to get it working to where I send the request to a php script and it adds the record to my DB and then it appends the new checkbox to the bottom of my list.  The issue I have is that I need to return the two values from PHP, the ID and the NAME.  Right now I can return the name but I am not sure how to return them separately so that I can manipulate them in the JS.

I might be going about this in the wrong way completely.  The idea is that I would create the new category records and then append them back to the category list using JS and then I would checkmark them and when I click "save" the values (IDs) would be sent to the current row (post) in the DB.

I hope i'm making some sense.  If you have any questions please ask away and if you have any ideas or answers please let me know!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try returning the text as JSON. Depending on the jQuery AJAX method you are using you can set a custom callback (a function that gets called after the first function has returned).

For example if you're using the $.post method you could do something like this:

backend.php:

```
$return_value = array();
$return_value['value1'] = 'data 1';
$return_value['value2'] = 'data 2';
echo json_encode($return_value);
```

frontend.js:

```
$.post("backend.php", '',
    function(data) {
        alert(data.value1); // Would show data 1
        alert(data.value2); // Would show data 2
}, "json");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have and idea of what you are trying to do:

Until now, you were returning the ID of the newly created category in plaintext from the php to the calling javascript.

Now you want to return *both* the ID and the NAME of the newly created category.

There are two ways to do this: using XML or JSON. (on may argue there are more ways. and indded, there are.)

in XML:

```
<response>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <NAME>jquery</NAME>
</response>
```

in JSON:

```
{
  id : 2,
  name : "jquery"
}
```

parsing JSON in javascript is a trivial matter.
parsing XML can be done using jQuery, just look up the jQuery ajax docs.

Cheers,

jrh.

Comment: For simple cases JSON is better. XML is preferred when you plan intercommunications between resources on smth. like client-server application.

Answer (score 0):

The most common method to return values is to use a JSON string [JSON wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

and then do

```
var p = eval(response.txt);
alert(p.var1);
alert(p.var2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$id` and `$name` are the values you want to return:

```
<?php

$id = 2;
$name = "jquery";

echo json_encode (array("id" => $id, "name" => $name));

?>
```

Then use any of the other answers for manipulating these values in Javascript.